# Grails createCriteria() used inside Domain classes

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class, grails-controller

Just got to know about the capability of createCriteria() method. Just wanna know that other than applying it on the Controller, is there a way to apply onto the domain classes as well? Probably on its own mapping to a property like:

```
static mapping = {
      additionalInfo: Page.createCriteria().list()
}
```

Comment: why as a mapping  ? why not `List<Page> getPages() {  Page.createCriteria().list()  as List<Page>}` or `List<Page> getPages() {  Page.findAllByClassName(this) as List<Page> }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you may want to simply create a new **field** based the **target field** like the below example:

```
class myInfo {
    String additionalInfo
    String[] moreInfo  // a transient field

    getMoreInfo(){
        def myresultmap = createCriteria.list{
         // insert any other criteria shenanigans
        }
        return myresultmap
    }
    static transients = ['moreInfo']
}
```

In a controller return a view like normal with the Domain instance of class MyInfo
Then use in view like:

```
<g:each in="${domaininstancefromcontroller}">
${it.moreInfo[0]
</g:each>
```

see [docs](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/transients.html).
Hope this helps.

Comment: usually when you only have 1 type i.e. typically a Getter. It is already a transient property so far as GORM is concerned, only when you apply bot get and set of something that you would wish to declare it as transient. The other thing with my example of List<Page> was that that model os safe to compile if @CompileStatic was to be used and if the method had a static calling method that it referred to ...

Comment: Hi, I tried the example and how do i added on my Controller? Tried to println myInfo.getMoreInfo() gives me groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException

Comment: http://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/Grails--Spring-Security-Plugin-configuration-for-login-using-either-username-or-email Try looking at some already done examples - spring security as an example generates getters for you in the user class. https://github.com/grails-plugins/grails-spring-security-core/blob/master/plugin/src/main/templates/Person.groovy.template#L24 either mess around by installing plugin and doing some basics with it or have a look at the example you can also write hql queries in your getters if you wanted to

Comment: Transients are not persistent so either do the calculations in the domain like the example and display in view or do calculations in controller and display in view

Comment: @Derrick Also if this helps please check answer correct

Answer (score 0):

> Just wanna know that other than applying it on the Controller, is
>   there a way to apply onto the domain classes as well?

Criteria queries are not limited to controllers, you can apply them elsewhere using the same syntax that you would in a controller.  However, the particular example you show there is probably going to be problematic because you are trying to use GORM inside of the `mapping` block which is used to configure GORM.